# Double breaker with only 120 volts at outlet

Tags: receptacle

[image]This circuit is on a double 15 amp breaker but at this location I removed a baseboard heater, I'm only getting 120v, so wondering if I can put a 15 amp outlet here, also the double whites show 120 volts, the double Blk show practically 0 volts

Comment: Picture of the double-breaker? Picture of the junction box showing the "double whites" and "double black"?

Comment: Actually still trying to identify the breaker that powers it, still, it only has 120 volts

Comment: It sounds like you want to add a receptacle, but the question is vague and confusing.

Comment: Yes I want to add an 15 amp outlet , but unclear as to why there is power on white instead of Blk, n this is the location where a baseboard heater was removed, though there is only 120 volts, on the white, next to 0 volts on the blk